# SharePoint 2010 CU and security Updates

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

I have just applied the SP 2010 March 2018 CU - KB 4011710

I got the qualys report to run and found "Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update March 2018" - KB4011709 is not installed.

Since March CU KB4011710 is applied, do we need to apply KB4011709?

The sword.dll in this location C:\Program Files\Microsoft SharePoint\14.0\WebServices\ConversionService\Bin\Converter\sword.dll  Version is  14.0.7015.1000

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you're running Office Web Apps you need to separately patch it.